# Inventory Management System In Php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I am workin on a project in which i need to design and hotel inventory management system below are mention few point which i need to keep in mind while creating such flow

1. user Interface of the system should look like an excel sheet where Column Should represent date and row should represent number of room in each category.
2. Boxes in user interface should be clickable.
3. by clicking on that box user should be able to block that particular cell and block his inventory
4. Also on second click on that block celll user should be able to open that block inventory
5. Blocked Inventory should show some icon like cross to represent that is inventory is blocked

Now below are few questions on which i would like to have your help.

1. How this user interface can be build on php
2. How i need to design my sql query
3. How database normalization should be done in such case

i have not build a single line of code so would not be able to share. would request you to suggest some artical or webpage where i can understand such inventory management system.

Thanks
Pratik Verma

Comment: This question is way too broad and hypothetical. Start writing the code and then ask a question about something specific, when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database aspect of your question:

To normalize you should make sure you don't have repeating information, generally don't store fields that are calculated, and make sure the relationships of your tables are one to many if possible. Assign meaningful primary and foreign keys that are unique to their tables. Referential integrity is key! I'd also stay away from null values.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robyn but... Still in unclear with the concept of such coding...

Comment: I'm no help with PHP. SQL specifics for your database will depend on the server you're using. SQL Server vs Oracle vs MySQL, etc